# Using Linkedin to signin into my iPhone native application

Tags: ios, ipad, linkedin-api

I have googled a lot on this and i have found integrations of Linkedin in an iPhone application which can be used for sharing purposes.

But my requirement is a bit diffrerent , what i need to do is :-

1. When i open my iPad native application , i want to use " Log In using Linked Account"
2. The user enters his Linked in credentials and once they are authenticated/validated the control comes back to my iPad native application .
3. The user continues exploring the rest of the application.

Now i have found a few links that explin how to use " Login using Linkedin feature " but it's for websites , i couldnt locate anything on how to log into my native application using LinkedIn credentials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the libraries and tools page on that developer site: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/libraries-and-tools

There is a link to an example iOS client application:
https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client

This application includes the OAuth dance as well as examples of read and write actions, and can be used as an example of how to implement OAuth in an application.

Answer (score 0):

[LinkedinIOSHelper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30876953/2317286) you can use this library if you want to. It is my library written well documentation to understand easily.