# iOS LinkedIn API error

Tags: ios, oauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to implement [this LinkedIn library](https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI) in my project, but it seems that I get an error while I try to present the LinkedIn screen:

> Authorization failed LinkedIn1: Error Domain=LIALinkedInERROR Code=1
>   "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LIALinkedInERROR error 1.)"

You can find the code that I am using [here](https://github.com/jeyben/IOSLinkedInAPI/issues/55).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May this information help you -

[image]

[API Terms of Use](https://e.linkedin.com/pub/cc?_ri_=X0Gzc2X%3DWQpglLjHJlYQGp4H6czdC9ek7oDLDEeft8eIog8zdPzao4nrlniU2DFVXtpKX%3DWBAABY&_ei_=EmxW4Se0XJN7XVtYKdJ2w_524p36RIyhVwew9s6qdX0nnwTr594SuNaqxS-it555kgN4a5fomiVg10)

[Transition Guide](https://e.linkedin.com/pub/cc?_ri_=X0Gzc2X%3DWQpglLjHJlYQGp4H6czdC9ek7oDLDEeft8eIog8zdPzao4nrlniU2DFVXtpKX%3DWTTUYY&_ei_=EmxW4Se0XJN7XVtYKdJ2w_524p36RIyhVwew9s6qdX0nnwTr594SuNaqxS-it555kgN4a5fomiVg10)

Comment: can you post a link to the page in cause?

Comment: [API Terms of Use] (https://e.linkedin.com/pub/cc?_ri_=X0Gzc2X%3DWQpglLjHJlYQGp4H6czdC9ek7oDLDEeft8eIog8zdPzao4nrlniU2DFVXtpKX%3DWBAABY&_ei_=EmxW4Se0XJN7XVtYKdJ2w_524p36RIyhVwew9s6qdX0nnwTr594SuNaqxS-it555kgN4a5fomiVg10.)

[transition guide] (https://e.linkedin.com/pub/cc?_ri_=X0Gzc2X%3DWQpglLjHJlYQGp4H6czdC9ek7oDLDEeft8eIog8zdPzao4nrlniU2DFVXtpKX%3DWTTUYY&_ei_=EmxW4Se0XJN7XVtYKdJ2w_524p36RIyhVwew9s6qdX0nnwTr594SuNaqxS-it555kgN4a5fomiVg10.)

Answer (score 11):

I also faced the same problem .My error was Error Domain=LIALinkedInERROR Code=2. On 26th May , 2016 the Linkedin has again made some changes due to which extra '#!' are added to the state and as a result ,the state do not match in LIALinkedInAuthorizationViewController class. So the solution is to remove those 2 characters either by replacing string or by checking contain string.

In the else part of this method `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {`

change to `

```
      NSString *receivedState = [[self extractGetParameter:@"state" fromURLString: url] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#!" withString:@""];
```

` or apply contains string so that the state is matched completely.

I know its kind of a weird solution but that did the trick for me. Hope it helps you as well.
All the best

[image]

Comment: After hours of search you gave me the solution... thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help buddy :)

Comment: Today I notice the same issue. Thanks a lot for the quick fix :)

Comment: Thanks, it helps for me too. I use https://github.com/ahmetkgunay/LinkedinIOSHelper. 
 But I use this library through pods and it needs in fix and update on github. I've written a letter to the library's author. Hope he will do it soon.

Comment: @KunalGupta works like charm.but could get user email address

Comment: Wow!! I'm glad I found your answer first instead of wasting hours! cheers @KunalGupta

Answer (score 3):

Since the 12th May Linkedin's API has changed. From now on any apps requesting `r_contactinfo` must be approved by LinkedIn. [This link](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) explains the changes.

I'm using this Library and just had to change the permissions from `@"r_contactinfo"` to `@"r_basicprofile", @"r_emailaddress"`.

Also remember to change your app permissions on developer.linkedin.com to match the above.

Comment: so what I am trying to retrieve is the users Skills & Endorsements, can you guide me in what I should do, is it mandatory to enter/ apply for the Partner Program?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you'll need access to `r_fullprofile` in order to get skills and endorsements. This now requires approval from LinkedIn (for which [you apply for here](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin)).

Comment: Thank you @jack for you help, I will try to become a member of the partner program if possible, 1+ for support

Answer (score 2):

You should have to use:

```
code=https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?
```

In place of:

```
code=https://www.linkedin.com//uas/oauth2/authorization?
```

Also in linkedin api:

```
LIALinkedInAuthorizationViewController.m
LIALinkedInHttpClient
```

Change:

```
NSString *accessTokenUrl = @"/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=%@&redirect_uri=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@";
```

By:

```
NSString *accessTokenUrl = @"/oauth/v2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code=%@&redirect_uri=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@";
```

Answer (score 0):

Jack's answer is absolutely true, [Jack's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30256321/2317286). In addition to this you can use this library also [LinkedinIOSHelper](https://github.com/ahmetkgunay/LinkedinIOSHelper) , it is easy to use

Comment: As a reminder, this site's [policy for self-promotion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59302/253560) requires you to indicate your affiliation with this project in the answer, even though its a non-commercial, open-source project. The indication can be as simple as saying "my library" instead of "Tthis library".

Comment: Thank you for your warning. I will be much more careful