# Request Error for Linkedin in Sharekit

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, sharekit

I have integrated LinkedIn in my IOS application using ShareKit. Whenever i try to share any images from the application it gives an alert saying "REQUEST ERROR - There was a problem requesting Authorization from LinkedIn".

Comment: Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232359/ios-linkedin-api-error/30232403#30232403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never...

You need to change line 37 in `SHKLinkedIn.m` to request the proper new permissions, as ShareKit's current usage of `rw_nus` is no longer valid:

```
#define SHKLinkedInRequiredScope @"w_share"
```

Comment: but now its giving me a security code and asking "Please return to your Application and Enter the following security code to grant access" i tried to enter the code in Application but couldn't find it . Please help me